# Running sqlcmd in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How can I run this command from an asp.net script? And have it output to the output.txt file?

```
C:\Users\administrator.user\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\script.sql -o C:\Users\administrator.user\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\output.txt");
```

Comment: `ReadAllText` requires a valid path to a file.  Why are you trying to pass command line arguments just to open a .sql file?

Comment: Rick - the paths I listed are valid. It functions fine without the -o (I am just trying to figure out how to output to the alert.txt using the -o without generating an error).

Comment: Maybe move the -o stuff inside your script file?  I don't what's in there so I can't give you answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that the paths you specify are going to be relevant on the machine on which SQL Server is running, NOT the machine on which the application is running (unless they happen to be the same machine of course).

Comment: This has all sorts of reasons *to not do this*.  Why not put your sql in a config file?

Comment: Erik - I tried it in a config file and it ran fine until I added the -> -o C:\Users\administrator.user\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\output.txt" -> then it generated an error.

Comment: Issue resolved by creating a new sql table and posting the output from within the original script.